# Finding kthSmallestElement in the BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am trying to solve the following question from LeetCode:

https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst/description/

> The aim is, given a BST, we have to find out the Kth-smallest element in it and return its value.

I could come up with a `O(n)` time and space solution myself.  But another solution which I wrote with online help is far better:

```
    /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    int kthSmallestUtil(TreeNode* root, int& k) {
        if(!root) return -1;

        int value=kthSmallestUtil(root->left, k);
        if(!k) return value;

        k--;
        if(k==0) return root->val;

        return kthSmallestUtil(root->right, k);
    }

    int kthSmallest(TreeNode* root, int k) {
        return kthSmallestUtil(root, k);
    }
};
```

I have understood the above solution.  I also debugged it (https://onlinegdb.com/BJnoIkrLM) by inserting break points at 29, 30, 33 and 37.  However, I still feel a bit uneasy because of the following reason:

In case of the call `kthSmallestUtil(root->left, k);`, we pass the original value of `k`; we then (understandably) decrement the value of `k` for the current root (since we are doing in order traversal).  But, when we again recurse for `kthSmallestUtil(root->right, k);`, why don't we pass the original value of `k`?  Why does the right child get a 'preferential' treatment - a decremented value of `k`?

I know because of debugging how the values of `k` change and we get the final answer.. But I am seeking some intuition behind using the original value of `k` for the left child and the decremented value of `k` for the right child.

Answer (score 0):

This solutions seems to assume an ordered binary search tree. 
That means the left branch of the tree contains only smaller values than the current nodes val. Thus it first recurses into the left branch, decrementing k along the way, then if k is not 0 k is decremented for the current element. If k is still not 0 then the values in the right branch, all greater than the current nodes value, are considered.

What you need to understand is that the k being decremented in the k--; line is not the original value of k but the value of k after the traversal of the entire left branch.

The recursive calls all modify the same k because k is passed by reference and not by value

Comment: Yes, so I get that - _the value of k after the traversal of the entire left branch_.  Suppose the value after the traversal of the entire left branch was `k1`.  Then for the current root, suppose we decremented `k1` and got the new value `k2`.  Now, before going into the right branch, why didn't we decrement `k2` (denoting the traversal (or visit) of the current node (root))?

Comment: `k2` is the decremented value in your example. You are confusing yourself, thinking current root and current node are different things. Check the code again. it does not ever acces it's own root. The `root` variable stores the current node, hence the `if(k==0) return root->val;` line.

Answer (score 0):

The code works more less this way - go as deep as you can in the left branch of the BST. When you reach the leftmost leaf - the smallest value - decrement `k` value and start seraching in the ramaining part of the BST. Because we already visited smallest value in the whole tree and we are searching for kth smallest value, we must search for `k-1`th smallest value in the rest of the tree (as we no longer take into account this leftmost leaf). And so, if `k` is equal to zero it means current node has the kth smallest value. Otherwise it is necessary to also search the right subtrees.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks! :)

Comment: So basically, we do that 'preferential' treatment because we are looking for the `k-1`th smallest node now (having already visited one prospective smallest node).  Am I right?

Comment: @Ganpat If I get You right - yes. We are ommiting in our search smallest element so from the rest we serach for `k-1`th smallest

Comment: one qq though - why then don't we decrease the value of `k` again (basically, `k-2`) when we pass the current root node?  As per your logic, since we have eliminated the possibility that the current node might be the target (`k!=0`), why are we not decrementing `k` again before going into the right child?

Comment: But we do decrease k in the line with `k--` for current root node. I mean, every node decreases the k for itself.

Comment: That `k--` is decrease **after** the left traversal of the tree - not again after the traversal (or visit) of the root.  Where is the `k` being decreased for the current root node, as per your statement _every node decreases the `k` for itself_?

Comment: The `k--` is the decrease for itself. If it was not found in left subtree (where every node decreased k) and still `k != 0` then it means that *this* node is not the kth one, so the k is decreased. I suggest you draw Yourself a graph and it will get less complicated.